# Modify width of Popover View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, uipopovercontroller

I am trying modify the width of my popover, which is a `UITableViewController`, so that it only takes up half of the width of the parent view. The popover is called programmatically when a button in another `UITableView` (the parent view) is tapped. I tried setting the `preferredContentSize` of the popover and setting the `sourceRect` but the popover still takes over the entire screen.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

...

func goToPlaces(button: UIButton) {

        let fromRect = CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, self.view.bounds.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.height)
        let popoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("otherPlaces")
        popoverVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
        presentViewController(popoverVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        popoverVC?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)
        popoverVC?.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.height)
        let popoverController = popoverVC?.popoverPresentationController
        popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = fromRect
        popoverController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        popoverController?.delegate = self


    }

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .None

    }
```

EDIT: 
When I do a print of 
`popoverPresentationController?.sourceView` and 
`popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect`

they both return nil for some reason

Comment: shouldn't the present statement be the last one? after you have configure everything?

Comment: @Rage I tried that before creating this question and it didn't make a difference. Very strange behavior to say the least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for

```
popoverVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
```

so you get it covering the whole screen. Try using:

```
popoverVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
```

The

```
presentViewController(popoverVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

should also be last so that the delegate can get the calls for which it wants to respond. (I think -- it might not matter if UIKit is actually delaying the presentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet`,

Comment: This doesn't work either. The popover rises from the bottom of my view and then covers then entire screen like the previous answers.

Comment: Change .pagesheet for .popover.